# SQL query to check if a data exist in a particular arrays of data

Tags: mysql, sql

My table structure looks like this

id, Name, Phone

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Phone numbers</th>
      
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td> 
        <td>Peter</td> 
        <td>1736736,67358467,553463563</td> 
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

So Peter has 3 numbers separated by commas in the phone column

So when a particular number calls I would like to check if it exist in the column phone. Something like

if 67358467 exist in column phone. The issue is the values in this column are separated by commas.

So what SQL query am I to use?

Comment: this is why it's almost always such a bad idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574

Comment: Are you trying to find stuff in an HTML table or a sql table???

Comment: Your example is HTML. Why do you want an SQL query?

Comment: No it is a MySQL table I just showed it structure using the HTML code

Answer (score 4):

There is a string function in MySQL called FIND_IN_SET which will help you find a number in a set.

Example...

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE FIND_IN_SET(1736736,numbers)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is how the table is defined. A single attribute should never contain multiple data. Think about using a table to join ID and numbers. So, you'll have a table mapping ID and person (1 to 1) and another table mapping ID and numbers (1 to n)

```
PEOPLE:
ID       NAME
1        Peter

PHONE_NUMBERS
ID      NUMBER
1       1736736
1       67358467
1       553463563
```

Your query will be:

```
select 1 from PEOPLE,PHONE_NUMBERS where NUMBER=<wanted_number> and PEOPLE.ID=PHONE_NUMBERS.ID
```

If result of this query is 1, then the number exists

Answer (score 0):

Something like: where phone like '%,number,%'

Comment: So then add: or phone like '%,number' or phone like 'number,%'

Comment: Same problem as the other answer. You might receive false positives if it matches only a part of the number.

Comment: Help me write the query. I am a little confuse at the moment

Comment: Do not think that. If doing 'number,%' if checks the column starts with the number plus a comma and doing '%,number' it checks the column ends with the number

Comment: select * from table_name where phone like '%,number,%' or phone like '%,number' or phone like 'number,%'